# If Modified Since Header in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, seo, http-headers

I am trying to enable `304 If Modified Since HTTP header` in my WordPress site. After doing lot of Googling I find out a site where the author said to put the following line at the very end of wordpress `wp-config.php` file. Here is the line of code:

```
header("Last-Modified: " . the_modified_date());
```

Now the author said that this was it. I dont have to do anything else to achieve `304 If Modified Since HTTP header`. But after doing this I tested by HTTP header using the site http://httpstatus.io/ and here is the screenshot of my header:

[image]
**(check the red marked section). The last modified header value is BLANK.**

After that I thought this might be some issue with `the_modified_date()` function so I've also tried `get_the_modified_date()` function. But still no result.

At the very end, I've created a small shortcode function to test if these functions are working or not and echoed it inside the short code. When I used the shortcode I can clearly see that the functions are working fine but for some reason sending blank to the `304 If Modified Since HTTP header`.

Please guys, help me to fix this issue. I'm out of clue and no idea how to achieve this.

P.S.: My site is [www.isaumya.com](http://www.isaumya.com)

Comment: Any help guys? Please take a look into this and help me out, along with many other wordpress users.

Comment: Look in your log files, how often does google send an if mod 304 request.

Comment: I dont understand your question. Google doesn't sent If modified, It reads the last modified header from the webpages.

Comment: Yes I know google loads the whole page, but I'm not sure that whether googlebot does the same for if modified since header activated sites. Most of the site does not use this feature so, as a googlebot they have to fetch the whole site. Beside this is a most important as mentioned my google webmaster guidelines.

Comment: As you can see that this topic is made for `WordPress` site where nothing is `HTML Static Content`, anything can be changed anytime the user wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the_modified_date()` is a template tag that must used inside the loop, that is why it is not wokring for you.

WordPress provide a action and filter hook to include or modify HTTP headers:

- [`send_headers` action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/send_headers)
- `wp_headers` filter (I don't find reference in codex)

But it doesn't work for this purpose. For example, the next code is not working:

```
add_action( 'send_headers', 'cyb_add_last_modified_header' );
function cyb_add_last_modified_header() {
    //Check if we are in a single post of any type (archive pages has not modified date)
    if( is_singular() ) {
        $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
        if( $post_id ) {
            header("Last-Modified: " . get_the_modified_time("D, d M Y H:i:s", $post_id) );
        }
    }
}
```

**Why?**

The main wp query is not build at this moment, neither in `wp_headers` filter. So, `is_singular()` returns `false`, `get_queried_object_id()` returns `NULL` and there is no way to get the modified time of the current post.

A posible solution is to use [`template_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) action hook, as suggested by Otto in [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20192/wp-function-filter-for-modifying-http-headers) (tested and working):

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'cyb_add_last_modified_header');
function cyb_add_last_modified_header($headers) {

    //Check if we are in a single post of any type (archive pages has not modified date)
    if( is_singular() ) {
        $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
        if( $post_id ) {
            header("Last-Modified: " . get_the_modified_time("D, d M Y H:i:s", $post_id) );
        }
    }

}
```

**Please Note**

The question is answered by [@cybmeta](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/37428/cybmeta) at [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/172966/if-modified-since-http-header/172968). I'm just sharing the answer here so that if anyone is looking for the answer here, he/she will find it. All credit goes to [@cybmeta](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/37428/cybmeta).